# ArgumentCapture doesn't work

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to verify my mockResource calling getQuantityString() passing the right quantity.

Actual code using getQuantityString()

```
resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.SUCCESS,5,5);
```

In test:

```
@Captor private ArgumentCaptor<Integer> firstIntegerCaptor;
verify(resources).getQuantityString(isA(int.class),firstIntegerCaptor.capture(), any());
```

I got error in below.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.junit.ArgumentsAreDifferent: 
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
resources.getQuantityString(
    isA(int),
    <Capturing argument>,
    <any>
);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
resources.getQuantityString(
    2131165186,
    5,
    5
);
```

I check the prototype of this function.

```
public String getQuantityString(int id, int quantity, Object... formatArgs)
```

Is error because of Object... formatArgs or Integer doesn't match int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
verify(resources).getQuantityString(anyInt(),firstIntegerCaptor.capture(),  Matchers.<Object>anyVararg());
```